# Can $ 2^{3^{4^{.^{.^{.^{n-1}}}}}}\equiv 1 \bmod {n} $ for some $n>7$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Prove or disprove that there isn't any positive integer $n>7$ such that the linear congruence below is true.

$  2^{3^{4^{.^{.^{.^{n-1}}}}}}\equiv 1 \bmod {n} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $2^{3^4}$, and it's easy to show $1\equiv2^{3^4}=2^{81} \pmod{511}$. Therefore, take $n=511$, $2^{3^{4^{.^{.^{.^{n-1}}}}}}-1$ is apparently a multiple of $2^{3^4}-1$ since $3^{4^{.^{.^{.^{n-1}}}}}$ is divisible by $3^4$ and 
$$2^{3^{4^{.^{.^{.^{510}}}}}}\equiv1 \pmod{511}$$
holds.

Comment: Note that if you don't want to do the calculation with $511$ you could just use $n=2^{81}-1$ instead since $2^{81}\equiv1$ is obvious that way.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Right. Also $511$ is an obvious factor since it is $2^9-1$.

Comment: T. H. A. N. K. Y. O. U.

Answer (score -1):

Note that $2$ mod $7$ has order $3$ (since $2^2 \equiv 4 \bmod 7$ and $2^3 \equiv 1 \bmod 7$).

So $2^{3^m} \equiv 1 \bmod 7$ for **any** $m\geq 1$.

Comment: -1 The modulus is not fixed at $7$.

Comment: Oh my bad...I was reading the title of the question!

Comment: The title has been edited!

Comment: Yes, admittedly it was a bit confusing. Now it's better.